# Can we stop checkout process on woocommerce using javascript manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

Can we stop checkout process on woocommerce using javascript manually?

I am using this code for submit and want to stop process if certain condition occurs. I tried return false but it doesn't work.

```
 JQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function() {
    var np = $('#notepopup').val();// val = 0
    if(ne == 0){
         return false;
    }
 });
```

please suggest something

Comment: What is variable `ne`? … Please could you add the complete code and the details about the context. Why do you want to stop checkout process? Why are you using Javascript? … Sorry but your question is just too vague actually and kind of unclear.

Comment: ne is just a variabe which i am defining updated code please check

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it goes inside if but return false or e.preventDefault()  doesn't hold process to the same page.

Comment: Yes I know I have tried myself with both… I think it doesn't work because there is at least another delegated event from the `<form>` and many other active code and events involved…

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a solution this now, the below code worked for me. It needs `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` and to use the event `checkout_place_order` to work like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
        jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('checkout_place_order', function(e) {
            console.log("Submission Stopped");
            return false;
        });
});
```

If you require WooCommerce's validation to run first before stopping the checkout, there is [a solution here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323404/woocommerce-trigger-checkout-form-validation)!

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the form from submitting by prevent its default behavior (submit):

```
$("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function(e) {
    if(ne == 0){
         e.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

More doc on [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

### Edit

Using these alerts,

```
$("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function(e) {
    alert("Before if ");
    if(ne == 0){
         alert("Inside if ");
         e.preventDefault();
    }
    alert("After if ");
 });
```

When exactly do you see you form submitted?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't prevent woocommerce checkout process

Comment: @rik - please note it is `e.preventDefault()`, I made a typo before, maybe that's why it didn't work..

Comment: @Alfred yes I tried that, still it processed to next page

Comment: Did you try the alerts? After which alert does it get send? We need to know if your jQuery selector is valid, ie. are you even getting inside the `submit` event...

Comment: yes, it shows all alerts. i think it shouldn't show last one. right ?

Comment: Are you sure you have only one form in the page? How do you submit the form? Using ajax? You may need to share full code here please.

Comment: its woocommerce checkout page, alerts are triggered but it processed to next page

Answer (score 2):

## Event Relay with Validator

Figured out a way of doing this by building a kind of Relay system for the submit events attached to the checkout.

Just treat the "canSubmit()" as your event handler and return true only if you want the checkout form to submit as normal.

```
( ($) => {

    var confirmDetails = true;

    function canSubmit( e ) {
        // Handle event here. Return true to allow checkout form to submit
        return false;
    }

    function init() {

        // Use set timeout to ensure our $( document ).ready call fires after WC
        setTimeout( () => {
            var checkoutForm = $( 'form.checkout' );

            // Get JQuery bound events
            var events = $._data( checkoutForm[0], 'events' );
            if( !events || !events.submit ) {
                return;
            }

            // Save Submit Events to be called later then Disable Them
            var submitEvents = $.map( events.submit, event => event.handler );
            $( submitEvents ).each( event => checkoutForm.off( 'submit', null, event ) );  

            // Now Setup our Event Relay
            checkoutForm.on( 'submit', function( e )  {
                e.preventDefault();
                var self = this;

                if( !canSubmit( ...arguments ) ) {
                    return;
                }

                // Trigger Event
                $( submitEvents ).each( ( i, event ) => {
                    var doEvent = event.bind( self );
                    doEvent( ...arguments );
                } );

            } );

        }, 10);
    }

    $( document ).ready( () => init() );

} )( jQuery );
```